# Accessible to the blind

Tags: flash

We installed your player in our website at www.speakingofradio.com and it works well. However, we didn't realize we would have as many blind people interested in the website as we do. Their one complaint is they can't get the player to work (or find it) with a screen reader. First, do you have any remedies we could use without overhauling the website and the player itself? I thought that maybe I should put a small line of text below the player (working as a link to start the player) and have the audio autoplay instead, but I can't find the code in my wordpress files or admin area to do this?

Todd

Comment: Whose "player" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Flash doesn't have many accessibility features. If I'm wrong about this, someone else can correct me, but I've always heard that that was one of the bad things about choosing that format.

You might want to look in to HTML5 video, or something other than Flash.

Also, you might want to reword this, it sounds like you copied and pasted from a support e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Since the player you use seems to be rather basic and simply plays a mp3 file, I guess you could just add a direct link to the mp3 file.

Comment: Sorry, the mp3 player we are using is mediaelement.js at www.mediaelementjs.com I would be happy if I could just make it a autoplay player so the blind wouldn't have to search for the on/off switch. However, I can't find the code to do this?